# Can't reset slider value after animating it in code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf

After animating my three slider values to `100`, `50`, and `20`, I can't change the values back to `1`. A reset button is coded to set them to `1` but they stay at `100`, `50`, and `20`!

Here's the code:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleAnimation sld_1anim = new DoubleAnimation(100, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        sld_1.BeginAnimation(Slider.ValueProperty, sld_1anim);
        DoubleAnimation sld_2anim = new DoubleAnimation(50, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        sld_2.BeginAnimation(Slider.ValueProperty, sld_2anim);
        DoubleAnimation sld_3anim = new DoubleAnimation(20, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        sld_3.BeginAnimation(Slider.ValueProperty, sld_3anim);
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) /// reset button NOT WORKS
    {
        sld_1.Value = 1;
        sld_2.Value = 1;
        sld_3.Value = 1;

        MessageBox.Show(sld_1.Value.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(sld_2.Value.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(sld_3.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint to your code and stepping through the program's execution?

Comment: @LewsTherin yes I did , there was nothing wrong

Comment: Does the code ever execute `Button_Click_1`?

Answer (score 1):

The default [`FillBehavior`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.fillbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) is `HoldEnd` which means your animation is going to hold it on that last value.

Pass `FillBehavior.Stop` as the third parameter to your animations.

```
new DoubleAnimation(20, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), FillBehavior.Stop)
```

As an aside; I would recommend just using a storyboard in XAML unless those numbers are going to become variable.

Comment: Thank you , but the problem is using FillBehavior.Stop resets the value to zero after animating , I don't want it reset automatically , I need to reset them with button.

Comment: @SamuelHardson You might be stuck between a rock and a hard place then. Perhaps bind the slider values and gradually change instead of an animation? I think there's a way to clear storyboards/animation but I don't remember what it is

Comment: Dear Bradley , I'm writing a new custom control and I need to use animator in code-behind . I can use another animator with 0 time to reset the value , but it can be painful for every element :D please if you remembered that tell me .

Comment: Just set the final value in a handler of the DoubleAnimation's Completed event. Or maybe immediately before starting the animation.